# Fill result of Canny edge detector opencv

Tags: opencv

Is there a way to fill the results of a Canny edge detector with white?

An alternative could be to detect whether a pixel or object is on the concave size of a curved edge.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canny detects edges, it does not make any guarantees about generating closed contours. Thus, "filling" is not always defined for the result.

If by some other means you know that some area is enclosed in a continuous closed contour, you could use e.g. flood-fill to fill it.